# How to implement resizeable fragment by user drag (not predefined transition animation)

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, android-transitions

Not sure how to explain this better, but it's mostly implemented by chat applications for Gallery picker fragments and alike. Best example is Google Allo, for which I posted GIF below. I'd like to know how is that implemented and how I could replicate the feature.

As you can see, the map fragment first transition animates from bottom to half of the screen, but then it can be dragged by finger to the top of the screen, when it actually fills the whole screen and even creates it's own toolbar. Most of all, I tested it, and this also works on API 16.

[image: a busy cat]